# How to get video size in react native?

Tags: react-native, video-upload

when uploading a video on, how to get its size.

I can set a limit to the duration but not the size.

I used this module

```
react-native-image-picker
```

this is the code used:

```
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';

  ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
  this.setState({ loading: false });

  if (response.didCancel) {
    console.log('User cancelled video picker');
  } else if (response.error) {
    console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
  } else {
    let path = '';
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      path = response.path;
    } else {
      path = response.uri;
    }
    const videoExtentionPos = path.lastIndexOf('.');
    const videoExtention = path.substring(videoExtentionPos + 1);

this.setState({
  fields: {
    ...fields,
    posts_video: {
      uri: response.uri,
      type: `video/${videoExtention}`,
      name: `video.${videoExtention}`
    }
  }
});
```

}
});

Comment: If you show you upload code maybe someone will be able to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not direct way to get it done. You will need to check the file size and show alert if it is not what you expect.
You can get the file size with rn-fetch-blob package.
You can use react-native-fs as well.